# How To Trim All Whitespace In an Elasticsearch Normalizer

Tags: elasticsearch

I found out that the normalizer with the `trim` filter is not trimming all whitespace characters, for example `\u2007` is not trimmed. Is there a way how to trim all whitespace characters in a normalizer? I tried to attach the pattern replace character filter to the normalizer, but this doesn't seem to be supported - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28605.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "trim"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Analyze API:**

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "normalizer" : "my_normalizer",
  "text" : " Hello"
}
```

Token generated is

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "hello",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "foo":" HellO "
}
{
    "foo":"hello "
}
{
    "foo":"hellO"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "foo": "hello"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67331196",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.105360515,
        "_source": {
          "foo": " hello"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67331196",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.105360515,
        "_source": {
          "foo": " Hello"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67331196",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.105360515,
        "_source": {
          "foo": " HellO "
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Milan Gatyas please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: thank you, I decoded the examples you posted and they all work with the \u0020 whitespace. Try to test your settings with the string  Hello - i.e. \u2007Hello\u2007, and you will see that the trim filter will not remove those characters.

Comment: @MilanGatyas I tried for `"  Hello  "` (two spaces before hello and two spaces after hello). The normalizer is working fine for this case also

Comment: I don't know how else I can stress out that regular spaces are trimmed correctly, but I have problem with the figure space - https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm, so e.g. " Hello " example. Regular " Hello " is not a problem.